# What is the difference between between toggle breakpoint and disable breakpoint in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, debug-symbols

There are few other questions on similar line, but I feel this is new. Thanks.

Comment: google is your friend.

Comment: [Define: toggle](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Atoggle), [Define: disable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Adisable)

Comment: English meaning is different from the behavior of such words in an IDE

If you disable the breakpoint, you can enable it again later (there will still be a marker on the line).

If you toggle it off, it will be deleted (Eclipse does not keep a marker on the line, so you have to find it again).

Answer (score 2):

If you disable the breakpoint, you can enable it again later (there will still be a marker on the line).

If you toggle it off, it will be deleted (Eclipse does not keep a marker on the line, so you have to find it again).

The distinction is even more important with conditional breakpoints (as they have some configuration, not just a line number), and when you get into the habit of doing "disable/enable all breakpoints".